# SQL three table join query

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
select
  dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,
  count(dbo.IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId) as Orders,
  sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from
  IN_Invoices
inner join
  CLOI_ClientOrderItems
on
  IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where
  datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2
and
  datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
group by
  cl_id
```

---

```
select
  sum(in_total)
from
  IN_Invoices
where
  datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2
and
  datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
```

From this query I am getting result of in_total and using this query I need to display cl_id and count(order)

Comment: Can you describe your desired output?

Comment: your first query dosen't work????

Comment: cl_id       orders    total
100000_ori    4         476 bur its wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the SELECT, assuming you are looking for the overall total for each cl_id.  Otherwise you need to add cl_id to the second query and do an INNER JOIN like in the first example.

```
DECLARE @param1 integer = 2
DECLARE @param2 integer = 2014

select
dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,
count(dbo.IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId) as Orders,
sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total,
OverallTotal = (select sum(in_total) from IN_Invoices where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=@param1 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=@param2)
from
 IN_Invoices
inner join
 CLOI_ClientOrderItems
on
 IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where
 datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=@param1
and
 datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=@param2
group by
 cl_id
```

Comment: Please see edit.  This generally means that you would need to wrap it as a stored procedure.

Comment: i have 3 tables howcan i sendto u

Comment: Oh.  I thought you were using SQL Server.  What database are you using?

Comment: Post errors or entire sql.  Use sqlfiddle if needed.